# Compiling: Log file not found

Tags: miktex, texmaker, texstudio

I have installed MikTex and Texmaker (also TexStudio if that is better) on my Windows 8.1. PC and when trying to compile, I get the error message "Log file not found". I am pretty sure that I just got the paths in the options wrong, but I have already tried everything I could find on the internet and nothing worked. Can you maybe tell me what exactly the log file does, where it should be and what file/application I am supposed to end up with when I type in the right command (I mean which application is going to do the actual compiling)?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. There have been a few questions about that error here before, are those among the thing's you've looked at? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=texmaker%20log%20file%20not%20found%20is%3aquestion

Comment: Do you have spaces or special utf8 characters in your file name?

Comment: @ Herbert - I had a space but I tried removing it already, doesn't change anything

Comment: update of information: with the help of a one-year-old comment by Ian I got to solve the log file error by just creating an empty log file in the folder my tex file is in. But now when it starts working, it keeps loading and does nothing in the end. Still, thanks a lot, Ian!